# htaccess append query to the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Currently I have the following code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.zip$ generator.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**Current problem:** My code drops the currently query (if available), and just pass the id.

I am trying to preserve the url query (it can exists or no) and append the id to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.zip$ generator.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves the existing query string from the URL.